# playing video on ancient computer

Tags: debian, vlc, mplayer

I'd like to play video stream on ancient computer (PII 400 + 512M). I installed debian with XLDE but iceweasel takes to much CPU - video is choppy. I was trying to cut everything unneeded - when there's no iceweasel - top shows 0.01 - if iceweasel starts playing - top rises 2-3

So, after few days of trying to slim X i changed the idea - not creating some website with video, but encode some video stream, which could be played by vlc or mplayer - so I try to run vlc -vo fbdev file.mp4 - but no video appears.. Now i'm stucked where to go... Please give me some advices...

Why i'm trying not to use X? Because Xorg consumes resources - CPU and RAM. So I think if removing xorg would give a missing bits.

Few subquestions:

1. which module should I use: 
   lspci:
   01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI 3D Rage Pro AGP 1X/2X (rev 5c)

I can use atyfb, aty128fb and eveb radeon (all have vendor: 1002 ("Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"), device: 4742 ("3D Rage PRO AGP 2X"))

2. I now use atyfb and got errors:

   $ vlc --vout /dev/fb0 /home/film.mp4
   VLC media player 2.0.3 Twoflower (revision 2.0.2-93-g77aa89e)
   [0x96cbe30] inhibit interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
   [0x96cbe30] main interface error: no suitable interface module
   [0x96bfb58] main interface error: no suitable interface module
   [0x96ab8f0] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
   [0x96ab8f0] main libvlc: Uruchamianie vlc z domyślnym interfejsem. Użyj 'cvlc' aby używać vlc bez interfejsu.
   [0x9739f88] qt4 interface error: Could not connect to X server
   [0x9739f88] skins2 interface error: cannot initialize OSFactory
   [0x9739f88] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
   VLC media player 2.0.3 Twoflower
   Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help.

   > [0x96ebfd8] main video output error: video output creation failed
   >   [0x96f7bb8] main decoder error: failed to create video output

Explanation - why i'm trying to do such thing on such lowend computer? Because i've got it and has no place for other - the only thing i want from this computer is to play loopless playlist on screen. Nothing more. I needed - I can resample movie to some other format/codec, but essentially - let's assume it is something better than picture frame, which slides pictuters endless

Comment: Using vlc or mplayer directly sounds like a good idea, but without any more information I have no idea what your problem might be.

Comment: In general, I'd expect mplayer/etc. to be faster outputting to X11 (via `-vo xv`) than fbdev. Any reason you don't run vlc under X11? Also, do you get any error messages? If so, please include them in your question.

Comment: What are the specs of your "ancient computer"?

Comment: I modify the question everytime commenters ask for be more precise